# Are #define (preprocessor directives) inherited from header files

Tags: c

If I have some `#define` in a header file, will it be usable in a source code that includes that header?
[Something like `#define Bytef unsigned int`]

Comment: This is not good question. Why'd you ask? Did you try it?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I am trying to fix a bug. At a changelog in zlib I found that change typedef with define. So I thought that the change is defined because we need to add "define" in the source. I tried to google that is define inherited, couldn't find results. SO i thought I should ask

Comment: The preprocessor will replace `#include` directives with the contents of the included file. I suggest you try to view the preprocessed source some time.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But then will it run again to set the "define" preprocessor directive?

Comment: @DakshShah HInt: try `gcc -E`. Hope it will help you to understand better. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh What about ANSI c?

Comment: @DakshShah what about ANSI c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

An include works as follows:

imagin you have a file.

```
header.h
```

content:

```
 void HappyMakerPrototype();
 void AnotherPrototype();
```

and a source file

```
src.c
```

content:

```
void dummydec();
#include "header.h"

void main ()
{
    return;
}
```

In the first step of compilation it will run through the preprocessing.

Here the include line just gets replaced by all the content of your included file.

So that If you would request the output for the preprocessed file it would look like:

(in gcc and clang compiler you can request the preprocessed file with parameter `-E` I guess that will help you understanding)

```
void dummydec();
void HappyMakerPrototype();
void AnotherPrototype();

void main ()
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Would you be so fair and correct me what is wrong with this? I would love to improve my knowledge and the post, too.

Comment: This is wrong, the `#define`s won't be in the output after the preprocessor is done. All preprocessor directives are handled by the preprocessor. Testing with `gcc -E` confirms this.

Comment: @unwind. I said "on the first run" To better show on what happens. I never said they will be in the output. I will clarify that.

Comment: @unwind: are you ok with that?

Comment: I still think it's pointless to talk about some imaginary "first run", that never happens in practice.

Comment: @unwind changed my example completly that there isn't need anymore for a limited consideration which is in an unlimited scope incorrect.

Comment: @unwind: That "first run" happens at least conceptually. The C standard uses the terms _source file_, _preprocessing translation unit_ (with the `#include`s resolved, as shown here before the edits) and _translation unit_ (the other preprocessing steps have been done).

Comment: @mafso Yes, I know, but the (original) argument in this answer was that you could see the preprocessing translation unit using e.g. `gcc -E` and that's not true.

Comment: @unwind THAT never was my intention to say. note I said the first step of compilation is the preprocessing. which the -E parameter was acording to. After that iw was talking of the first step of the preprocessing, which isn' the same as the first step of compilation. So I was talking about 2 different things.

Comment: @Zaibis OK, fine. I removed my down-vote ages ago, not sure what else I can do here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do. While you are including that header file it will inherit all the things from that header. So you can use that Macro.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Including a file is as the same as if you copy and pasted the contents of the header file at the exact location as the `#include` directive.